# firefox addon, transparent floating panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, panel, floating

I'm developing a firefox addon and would like to have a fixed position (relative to the browser) semitransparent panel with 3 icons shown at the corner of every browser content area. These buttons will have to be able to communicate with a site that is not the site shown.

I know it would be possible to inject a fixed position div to html but I want the buttons to communicate with external site when pressed and also query information when they are loaded so I think that would violate same origin policy. This wouldn't work with image or other direct media urls either.

What would be the easiest way to create the floating icon panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about of week of work I found it. Here is the answer, I hope this helps someone else:

http://marcada.ms/2010/02/getting-content-on-top-of-the-browser-space-using-xul/

The above adds the panel, transparency is not working (at least not in linux what I work with) because of the following bug. Sigh... opened in 2007 and not closed in 2012.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408284

edit2: I ended inserting html data to the body of the document using files from extension folder. Works very well including transparency.

edit3: If anyone is interested how this works in my plugin, check my live site at http://www.upmarker.com